# How to get the range of values from the slicer after the current selection in the slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a slicer in power bi , in which I am trying to get the all the slicer values which are after the current selection in the slicer, I am trying for a while and its not working , I have also tried to create the calculated table and its still not working for me , this is the measure which I am trying to create to get all the values after the current selection

```
RangeAfterSelection = 
VAR SelectedQuarter = SELECTEDVALUE(Query1[from_quarter])
RETURN
    CALCULATETABLE(
        DISTINCT(Query1[from_quarter]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(Query1),
            Query1[from_quarter] > SelectedQuarter &&
            RIGHT(Query1[from_quarter], 4) <= "2022"
        )
    )
```

So when I try to put this measure in the table , it gives me an error of

```
a table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected
```

I have values in the slicer text format like this
**from_quarter**

```
2011-Q1
2011-Q2

Till 
2022-Q2
```

Data is like this

[image]

Comment: You are dealing with only one table ? Query1[from_quarter] can you provide some data from this column ?

Comment: yes @AmiraBedhiafi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't only rely on the text values in you slicers, you need to add a numeric value to sort like below :

[image]

and try to order the from_quarter by the FromQYYYY :

[image]

And then create two new tables to use them as the slicers:

```
From = SELECTCOLUMNS(
    MyTable,
    "From", MyTable[from_quarter],
    "FromQYYYY", MyTable[FromQYYYY]
)

To = SELECTCOLUMNS(
    MyTable,
    "To", MyTable[from_quarter],
    "ToQYYYY", MyTable[FromQYYYY]
)
```

Don't create any relationships between the tables :

[image]

and then create the following measure :

```
CheckQuarter = 
VAR fromfilter = SELECTEDVALUE('From'[FromQYYYY])
VAR tofilter =  SELECTEDVALUE('To'[ToQYYYY])
RETURN 
IF(SELECTEDVALUE(MyTable[FromQYYYY]) >= fromfilter && SELECTEDVALUE(MyTable[ToQYYYY]) <= tofilter, 1)
```

Then to visualize the result, use the following :

- slicer from : use the column From[From]
- slicer to : use the column To[To]
- in the visual displaying the result add the measure CheckQuarter=1 as a filter on the visual :

[image]